# How to tilt to match vertical movement with Unity A* pathfinding Ai

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, game-physics, path-finding

Hello im using the A* pathfinding and i use the Ai example "aipath" but i have the on hill roation script that makes this achived

[image]

but wen i add the script it starts to do this to the object :
https://gfycat.com/gifs/detail/ValidSneakyDogwoodtwigborer
it makes it glitch alot:

and wen does not have the on hill rotaion script its fine :
https://gfycat.com/upload/results

here is the Ai script :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Pathfinding;
using Pathfinding.RVO;
using Pathfinding.Util;

/** AI for following paths.
 * This AI is the default movement script which comes with the A* Pathfinding Project.
 * It is in no way required by the rest of the system, so feel free to write your own. But I hope this script will make it easier
 * to set up movement for the characters in your game.
 * This script works well for many types of units, but if you need the highest performance (for example if you are moving hundreds of characters) you
 * may want to customize this script or write a custom movement script to be able to optimize it specifically for your game.
 * \n
 * \n
 * This script will try to follow a target transform. At regular intervals, the path to that target will be recalculated.
 * It will in the #Update method try to move towards the next point in the path.
 * However it will only move in roughly forward direction (Z+ axis) of the character, but it will rotate around it's Y-axis
 * to make it possible to reach the target.
 *
 * \section variables Quick overview of the variables
 * In the inspector in Unity, you will see a bunch of variables. You can view detailed information further down, but here's a quick overview.\n
 * The #repathRate determines how often it will search for new paths, if you have fast moving targets, you might want to set it to a lower value.\n
 * The #target variable is where the AI will try to move, it can be a point on the ground where the player has clicked in an RTS for example.
 * Or it can be the player object in a zombie game.\n
 * The speed is self-explanatory, so is #rotationSpeed, however #slowdownDistance might require some explanation.
 * It is the approximate distance from the target where the AI will start to slow down.\n
 * #pickNextWaypointDist is simply determines within what range it will switch to target the next waypoint in the path.\n
 *
 * Below is an image illustrating several variables as well as some internal ones, but which are relevant for understanding how it works.
 * \note The image is slightly outdated, replace forwardLook with pickNextWaypointDist in the image and ignore the circle for pickNextWaypointDist.
 *
 * \shadowimage{aipath_variables.png}
 * This script has many movement fallbacks.
 * If it finds an RVOController attached to the same GameObject as this component, it will use that. If it fins a character controller it will also use that.
 * Lastly if will fall back to simply modifying Transform.position which is guaranteed to always work and is also the most performant option.
 */
[RequireComponent(typeof(Seeker))]
[AddComponentMenu("Pathfinding/AI/AIPath (2D,3D)")]
[HelpURL("http://arongranberg.com/astar/docs/class_a_i_path.php")]
public class AIPath : AIBase {
    /** Determines how often it will search for new paths.
     * If you have fast moving targets or AIs, you might want to set it to a lower value.
     * The value is in seconds between path requests.
     */
    public float repathRate = 0.5F;

    /** Target to move towards.
     * The AI will try to follow/move towards this target.
     * It can be a point on the ground where the player has clicked in an RTS for example, or it can be the player object in a zombie game.
     */
    Vector3 target;


    /** Enables or disables searching for paths.
     * Setting this to false does not stop any active path requests from being calculated or stop it from continuing to follow the current path.
     * \see #canMove
     */
    public bool canSearch = true;

    /** Enables or disables movement.
     * \see #canSearch
     */
    public bool canMove = true;

    public bool enableRotation = true; //delete


    /** Maximum velocity.
     * This is the maximum speed in world units per second.
     */
    public float speed = 3;

    /** Rotation speed.
     * Rotation is calculated using Quaternion.RotateTowards. This variable represents the rotation speed in degrees per second.
     * The higher it is, the faster the character will be able to rotate.
     */
    [UnityEngine.Serialization.FormerlySerializedAs("turningSpeed")]
    public float rotationSpeed = 360;

    /** Distance from the target point where the AI will start to slow down.
     * Note that this doesn't only affect the end point of the path
     * but also any intermediate points, so be sure to set #pickNextWaypointDist to a higher value than this
     */
    public float slowdownDistance = 0.6F;

    /** Determines within what range it will switch to target the next waypoint in the path */
    public float pickNextWaypointDist = 2;

    /** Distance to the end point to consider the end of path to be reached.
     * When the end is within this distance then #OnTargetReached will be called and #TargetReached will return true.
     */
    public float endReachedDistance = 0.2F;

    /** Draws detailed gizmos constantly in the scene view instead of only when the agent is selected and settings are being modified */
    public bool alwaysDrawGizmos;

    /** Time when the last path request was sent */
    protected float lastRepath = -9999;

    /** Current path which is followed */
    protected Path path;

    protected PathInterpolator interpolator = new PathInterpolator();

    /** Only when the previous path has been returned should be search for a new path */
    protected bool canSearchAgain = true;

    /** True if the end of the path has been reached */
    public bool TargetReached { get; protected set; }

    /** True if the Start function has been executed.
     * Used to test if coroutines should be started in OnEnable to prevent calculating paths
     * in the awake stage (or rather before start on frame 0).
     */
    private bool startHasRun = false;

    /** Point to where the AI is heading */
    protected Vector3 targetPoint;

    protected Vector3 velocity;

    /** Rotation speed.
     * \deprecated This field has been renamed to #rotationSpeed and is now in degrees per second instead of a damping factor.
     */
    [System.Obsolete("This field has been renamed to #rotationSpeed and is now in degrees per second instead of a damping factor")]
    public float turningSpeed { get { return rotationSpeed/90; } set { rotationSpeed = value*90; } }

    /** Starts searching for paths.
     * If you override this function you should in most cases call base.Start () at the start of it.
     * \see #Init
     */
    protected virtual void Start () {
        startHasRun = true;
        Init();
        target = transform.position;
        canMove = false;
    }

    /** Called when the component is enabled */
    protected virtual void OnEnable () {
        // Make sure we receive callbacks when paths are calculated
        seeker.pathCallback += OnPathComplete;
        Init();
    }





    private void MoveSelectedToCursorPosition()
    {
        RaycastHit raycastHit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out raycastHit, 1000.0f))
        {
            target = raycastHit.point;
            canMove = true;

        }
    }

    void Init () {
        if (startHasRun) {
            lastRepath = float.NegativeInfinity;
            StartCoroutine(RepeatTrySearchPath());
        }

    }

    public void OnDisable () {
        seeker.CancelCurrentPathRequest();

        // Release current path so that it can be pooled
        if (path != null) path.Release(this);
        path = null;

        // Make sure we no longer receive callbacks when paths complete
        seeker.pathCallback -= OnPathComplete;
    }

    /** Tries to search for a path every #repathRate seconds.
     * \see TrySearchPath
     */
    protected IEnumerator RepeatTrySearchPath () {
        while (true) yield return new WaitForSeconds(TrySearchPath());
    }

    /** Tries to search for a path.
     * Will search for a new path if there was a sufficient time since the last repath and both
     * #canSearchAgain and #canSearch are true and there is a target.
     *
     * \returns The time to wait until calling this function again (based on #repathRate)
     */
    public float TrySearchPath () {

        if (Time.time - lastRepath >= repathRate && canSearchAgain && canSearch && target != null) {
            SearchPath();
            return repathRate;
        } else {
            float v = repathRate - (Time.time-lastRepath);
            return v < 0 ? 0 : v;
        }
    }

    /** Requests a path to the target */
    public virtual void SearchPath () {
        if (target == null) throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Target is null");

        lastRepath = Time.time;
        // This is where we should search to
        Vector3 targetPosition = target;

        canSearchAgain = false;

        // Alternative way of requesting the path
        //ABPath p = ABPath.Construct(GetFeetPosition(), targetPosition, null);
        //seeker.StartPath(p);

        // We should search from the current position
        seeker.StartPath(GetFeetPosition(), targetPosition);
    }

    public virtual void OnTargetReached () {
        // The end of the path has been reached.
        // If you want custom logic for when the AI has reached it's destination
        // add it here.
        // You can also create a new script which inherits from this one
        // and override the function in that script
        canMove = false;

    }

    /** Called when a requested path has finished calculation.
     * A path is first requested by #SearchPath, it is then calculated, probably in the same or the next frame.
     * Finally it is returned to the seeker which forwards it to this function.\n
     */
    public virtual void OnPathComplete (Path _p) {
        ABPath p = _p as ABPath;

        if (p == null) throw new System.Exception("This function only handles ABPaths, do not use special path types");

        canSearchAgain = true;

        // Claim the new path
        p.Claim(this);

        // Path couldn't be calculated of some reason.
        // More info in p.errorLog (debug string)
        if (p.error) {
            p.Release(this);
            return;
        }

        // Release the previous path
        if (path != null) path.Release(this);

        // Replace the old path
        path = p;

        // Make sure the path contains at least 2 points
        if (path.vectorPath.Count == 1) path.vectorPath.Add(path.vectorPath[0]);
        interpolator.SetPath(path.vectorPath);

        var graph = AstarData.GetGraph(path.path[0]) as ITransformedGraph;
        movementPlane = graph != null ? graph.transform : GraphTransform.identityTransform;

        // Reset some variables
        TargetReached = false;

        // Simulate movement from the point where the path was requested
        // to where we are right now. This reduces the risk that the agent
        // gets confused because the first point in the path is far away
        // from the current position (possibly behind it which could cause
        // the agent to turn around, and that looks pretty bad).
        interpolator.MoveToLocallyClosestPoint((GetFeetPosition() + p.originalStartPoint) * 0.5f);
        interpolator.MoveToLocallyClosestPoint(GetFeetPosition());
    }

    public virtual Vector3 GetFeetPosition () {
        if (controller != null && controller.enabled) {
            return tr.TransformPoint(controller.center) - Vector3.up*controller.height*0.5F;
        }

        return tr.position;
    }


    /** Called during either Update or FixedUpdate depending on if rigidbodies are used for movement or not */
    protected override void MovementUpdate (float deltaTime) {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            MoveSelectedToCursorPosition();
        }



        if (!canMove) return;

        if (!interpolator.valid) {
            velocity2D = Vector3.zero;
        } else {
            var currentPosition = tr.position;

            interpolator.MoveToLocallyClosestPoint(currentPosition, true, false);
            interpolator.MoveToCircleIntersection2D(currentPosition, pickNextWaypointDist, movementPlane);
            targetPoint = interpolator.position;
            var dir = movementPlane.ToPlane(targetPoint-currentPosition);

            var distanceToEnd = dir.magnitude + interpolator.remainingDistance;
            // How fast to move depending on the distance to the target.
            // Move slower as the character gets closer to the target.
            float slowdown = slowdownDistance > 0 ? distanceToEnd / slowdownDistance : 1;

            // a = v/t, should probably expose as a variable
            float acceleration = speed / 0.4f;
            velocity2D += MovementUtilities.CalculateAccelerationToReachPoint(dir, dir.normalized*speed, velocity2D, acceleration, speed) * deltaTime;
            velocity2D = MovementUtilities.ClampVelocity(velocity2D, speed, slowdown, true, movementPlane.ToPlane(rotationIn2D ? tr.up : tr.forward));



            if (distanceToEnd <= endReachedDistance && !TargetReached) {
                TargetReached = true;
                OnTargetReached();
            }

            // Rotate towards the direction we are moving in
            var currentRotationSpeed = rotationSpeed * Mathf.Clamp01((Mathf.Sqrt(slowdown) - 0.3f) / 0.7f);
            RotateTowards(velocity2D, currentRotationSpeed * deltaTime);

            var delta2D = CalculateDeltaToMoveThisFrame(movementPlane.ToPlane(currentPosition), distanceToEnd, deltaTime);
            Move(currentPosition, movementPlane.ToWorld(delta2D, verticalVelocity * deltaTime));

            velocity = movementPlane.ToWorld(velocity2D, verticalVelocity);
        }
    }

    /** Direction that the agent wants to move in (excluding physics and local avoidance).
     * \deprecated Only exists for compatibility reasons.
     */
    [System.Obsolete("Only exists for compatibility reasons.")]
    public Vector3 targetDirection {
        get {
            return (targetPoint - tr.position).normalized;
        }
    }

    /** Current desired velocity of the agent (excluding physics and local avoidance but it includes gravity).
     * \deprecated This method no longer calculates the velocity. Use the #velocity property instead.
     */
    [System.Obsolete("This method no longer calculates the velocity. Use the velocity property instead")]
    public Vector3 CalculateVelocity (Vector3 position) {
        return velocity;
    }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    [System.NonSerialized]
    int gizmoHash = 0;

    [System.NonSerialized]
    float lastChangedTime = float.NegativeInfinity;

    protected static readonly Color GizmoColor = new Color(46.0f/255, 104.0f/255, 201.0f/255);

    protected override void OnDrawGizmos () {
        base.OnDrawGizmos();
        if (alwaysDrawGizmos) OnDrawGizmosInternal();
    }

    void OnDrawGizmosSelected () {
        if (!alwaysDrawGizmos) OnDrawGizmosInternal();
    }

    void OnDrawGizmosInternal () {

        var newGizmoHash = pickNextWaypointDist.GetHashCode() ^ slowdownDistance.GetHashCode() ^ endReachedDistance.GetHashCode();

        if (newGizmoHash != gizmoHash && gizmoHash != 0) lastChangedTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
        gizmoHash = newGizmoHash;
        float alpha = alwaysDrawGizmos ? 1 : Mathf.SmoothStep(1, 0, (Time.realtimeSinceStartup - lastChangedTime - 5f)/0.5f) * (UnityEditor.Selection.gameObjects.Length == 1 ? 1 : 0);

        if (alpha > 0) {
            // Make sure the scene view is repainted while the gizmos are visible
            if (!alwaysDrawGizmos) UnityEditor.SceneView.RepaintAll();
            if (targetPoint != Vector3.zero) Draw.Gizmos.Line(transform.position, targetPoint, GizmoColor * new Color(1, 1, 1, alpha));
            Gizmos.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(transform.position, transform.rotation, Vector3.one);
            Draw.Gizmos.CircleXZ(Vector3.zero, pickNextWaypointDist, GizmoColor * new Color(1, 1, 1, alpha));
            Draw.Gizmos.CircleXZ(Vector3.zero, slowdownDistance, Color.Lerp(GizmoColor, Color.red, 0.5f) * new Color(1, 1, 1, alpha));
            Draw.Gizmos.CircleXZ(Vector3.zero, endReachedDistance, Color.Lerp(GizmoColor, Color.red, 0.8f) * new Color(1, 1, 1, alpha));
        }
    }
#endif

    protected override int OnUpgradeSerializedData (int version) {
        // Approximately convert from a damping value to a degrees per second value.
        if (version < 1) rotationSpeed *= 90;
        return 1;
    }

}
```

Here is the on hill rotation script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class rotationOnHills : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray GroundRay = new Ray(transform.position, -transform.up);

        if (Physics.Raycast(GroundRay, out hit))
        {
            transform.up = hit.normal;
            transform.position = hit.point;

        }
    }
}
```

i have tried to add the rotation script on the capsule mesh and it doesnt work if i dont add the capsule collider but then if i dont have it on the Ai object it will fly away for no reason and that will happen if i have the rigbody and the collider on the capsule mesh .

Comment: Second link is broken

Answer (score 1):

The second script won't work, because rotations are unfortunately much more complex than that.

In your first script, try adding this to the end of `MovementUpdate`

```
RaycastHit hit;
Ray GroundRay = new Ray(transform.position, -transform.up);

if (Physics.Raycast(GroundRay, out hit))
{    
    transform.lookAt(transform.position + velocity.normalized, hit.normal);
}
```

This says that the transform should look where it is moving, with an upward direction equal to the normal of the hit

Edit: Missed that you're rotating at a fixed speed and already have some rotation code in `MovementUpdate`. You can change

```
// Rotate towards the direction we are moving in
var currentRotationSpeed = rotationSpeed * Mathf.Clamp01((Mathf.Sqrt(slowdown) - 0.3f) / 0.7f);
>>>RotateTowards(>>velocity2D<<, currentRotationSpeed * deltaTime);<<<

var delta2D = CalculateDeltaToMoveThisFrame(movementPlane.ToPlane(currentPosition), distanceToEnd, deltaTime);
Move(currentPosition, movementPlane.ToWorld(delta2D, verticalVelocity * deltaTime));

velocity = movementPlane.ToWorld(velocity2D, verticalVelocity);
```

to

```
// Rotate towards the direction we are moving in
var currentRotationSpeed = rotationSpeed * Mathf.Clamp01((Mathf.Sqrt(slowdown) - 0.3f) / 0.7f);

var delta2D = CalculateDeltaToMoveThisFrame(movementPlane.ToPlane(currentPosition), distanceToEnd, deltaTime);
Move(currentPosition, movementPlane.ToWorld(delta2D, verticalVelocity * deltaTime));

velocity = movementPlane.ToWorld(velocity2D, verticalVelocity);
>>>RotateTowards(>>velocity<<, currentRotationSpeed * deltaTime);<<<
```

Basically, rotate in 3D instead of 2D

Comment: O sorry im in school cant right now but it seems right

Comment: it didnt work i mean it its trying to do it and does it sometimes bur really rare this is how it looks now https://imgur.com/a/sspBk

Comment: @ZidLyx What is the error that's popping up? And can you show your updated MovementUpdate?

Comment: there is no error @Mars but here is the script https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6836e506fddc6c8a459e0c93fdc5c4f1

Comment: You have 3 rotates in there! Let's remove the last part (from Raycast down). Let's also remove the first RotateTowards  [>>>RotateTowards(>>velocity2D<<, currentRotationSpeed * deltaTime);<<<]

Comment: I posted on your link as well, so you can copy and paste

Comment: @ZidLyx oops, forgot to tag you

Comment: i did add it now and now it looks like this :  
 https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b237db9b56244bb9aacb00f59b922c77 and it does this the ..end of the green line is the target and its not going on it ;   https://gfycat.com/gifs/detail/SpiffySparklingAracari

Comment: forgot the tag you  sorry

Comment: @ZidLyx Was that the only change you made? Looks totally fine now.. Although I don't know what value you're producing for "velocity." You might need (transform.position + velocity)

Comment: PS, this is my answer, so I automatically receive a notification when you comment. No need to tag :)